# GWT: How to embed a SimplePager into a DataGrid

Tags: gwt

Currently, DataGrid doesn't include a SimplePager. One must create a composite and wrap a grid and a pager into a FlowPanel. Is there a way you can create a wrapper CDataGrid (that extends DataGrid) that includes SimplePager?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding pager as a part of the Grid, eliminates extra markup and steps in Compositve View. My solution was to create a new composite and provide callbacks.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you can use [UiBinder](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiBinder) to make this possible, you can check at the showcase sample [here](http://gwt.google.com/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwDataGrid) that shows this:

```
<!DOCTYPE ui:UiBinder SYSTEM "http://dl.google.com/gwt/DTD/xhtml.ent">
<ui:UiBinder
  xmlns:ui="urn:ui:com.google.gwt.uibinder"
  xmlns:g="urn:import:com.google.gwt.user.client.ui"
  xmlns:c="urn:import:com.google.gwt.user.cellview.client">

  <g:DockLayoutPanel
    unit="EM">
    <!-- DataGrid. -->
    <g:center>
      <c:DataGrid
        ui:field='dataGrid' />
    </g:center>

    <!-- Pager. -->
    <g:south
      size="3">
      <g:HTMLPanel>
        <table
          style="width:100%">
          <tr>
            <td
              align='center'>
              <c:SimplePager
                ui:field='pager' />
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </g:HTMLPanel>
    </g:south>
  </g:DockLayoutPanel>
</ui:UiBinder>
```

You can wrap a DataGrid with SimplePager or whatever do you wish, and make a new "Widget" called "CDataGrid" (as you said) that not extends DataGrid but can extends Composite.

I hope I can give you a little help with this.

Best Regards,

iVieL.

Answer (score 0):

It does integrate with DateGrid.
Take a look at the showcase for an example:
http://gwt.google.com/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwDataGrid